# Get zsh not to complete users

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, cd-command

I have a directory with a single subdirectory named `src`. I'd expect when typing in `cd s` and hitting `TAB` for the directory to be completed. Instead, `zsh` tries to complete all users on the system starting with a `s`:

```
Completing local directory
src/
Completing user
saeumair  sbrg      scan-nix  schlosse  sdwoods   shutdown   
sis-user  smmsp     snitch    srabhina  sshd      sterpeni  sushid    sync
```

I'm guessing the guilty line in my `.zshrc` is:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:directory-stack' list-colors '=(#b) \
        #([0-9]#)*( *)==95=38;5;12'
```

Which I'm using to be able to complete `cd` history. Any idea how I can keep this functionality while not completing for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are valid parameters for the `cd` command, and thus are offered as completion, because you have the option [`cdable_vars`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CDABLE_005fVARS) turned on. With this option, `cd foo` can be used instead of `cd ~foo`, which allows `foo` to be anything that can be [tilde-expanded](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion), including a user name or a directory name set by `hash -d` (but not shell variables, despite the name of the option).

There is no option in the completion code to allow named directories but not attempt to complete them. You could work around this with a wrapper to the completion function for `cd`.

```
unset -f _cd
autoload -U _cd
functions[_cd_orig]=_cd
_cd () {
  setopt local_options no_cdable_vars
  _cd_orig $@[@]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `cdablevars` option is responsible for making named directories and hence users a valid argument to cd. If you don't use that, use `unsetopt cdablevars`.

To change what is completed for cd, you can use the `tag-order` style. For example, to try only local-directories first, it would be:

```
    zstyle ':completion:*:cd:*' tag-order local-directories
```

A handy key shortcut for seeing the applicable tags in a certain context is to press `Ctrl-X h` instead of `tab`.